# How to echo only 1st line from 'curl' command output?

Tags: curl, stdout, head, cut

I'm trying to get only first line of the `curl` command output. (Sorry if this is confusing)

Let's say, for an instance, i run simply:

```
# curl http://localhost
<!-- This is the hidden line i want to grab. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
..
..
```

What to do if i want the very first line of the output here, which is:

```
<!-- This is the hidden line i want to grab. -->
```

I've tried things like this, but no luck yet:

```
# curl http://localhost | head -n 1
# curl http://localhost | sed -n '1!p'
```

.. etc. All gives me rubbish outputs, like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!-- This is the hidden line i want to grab. -->
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (173 != 1763)
```

It's not the output as expected as mentioned above:

```
<!-- This is the hidden line i want to grab. -->
```

Any experts here please =(

Comment: What kind of rubbish output? This: `curl -s http://example.com/ | head -n1` should work correctly, unless your output is compressed.

Comment: Edited the question to let you know what are the `rubbish outputs` means. Thanks.

Comment: Just add `-s` parameter to mute any progress output (rubbish). This still goes to stderr, so it won't be saved into the file if you redirect it somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This so called rubbish output is basically a progress meter during operation of downloading the data. You can basically ignore that, since it is by default going into [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) stream which is ignored, so only relevant part is printed out to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29).

Here is the test:

```
$ curl http://example.com/ | head -n1 > example.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1270  100  1270    0     0   112k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  124k
(23) Failed writing body
$ cat example.html 
<!doctype html>
```

If you still want to silence it, add `-s` parameter for quiet mode or redirect standard error stream into `/dev/null`, for example:

```
$ curl -s http://example.com/ 2> /dev/null | head -n1
<!doctype html>
```

Or using command substitution:

```
head -n1 <(curl -s http://example.com/ 2> /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **AWK** to print the first line of the output
*Example:*

```
$ curl -skI -XGET 'http://example.com' | awk 'NR==1'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer even if this is an old topic: instead of cutting the curl output, you may try with

$ curl http://localhost -o localhost.txt

$ head -n 1 localhost.txt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).